# Problem accessing spring boot metric endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus

I am having difficulty accessing `/metrics` endpoint when i added following classes -

ExporterRegister.class

```
public class ExporterRegister {
    private List<Collector> collectors;

    public ExporterRegister(List<Collector> collectors) {
        for (Collector collector : collectors) {
            collector.register();
        }
        this.collectors = collectors;
    }

    public List<Collector> getCollectors() {
        return collectors;
    }
}
```

CollectorRegistry.class

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(CollectorRegistry.class)
public class MetricController {
    private static final CollectorRegistry metricRegistry = CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry;

    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean registerPrometheusExporterServlet() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new MetricsServlet(metricRegistry), new String[]{"/metrics"});

    }

    @Bean
    ExporterRegister exporterRegister() {
        List<Collector> collectors = new ArrayList<>();
        collectors.add(new StandardExports());
        collectors.add(new MemoryPoolsExports());
        collectors.add(new GarbageCollectorExports());
        collectors.add(new ThreadExports());
        ExporterRegister register = new ExporterRegister(collectors);
        return register;
    }
}
```

I am using spring boot 2.1.4 version and following are the prometheus dependencies i am using in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient_spring_boot</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_hotspot</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_servlet</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

my application properties  -

```
 server.servlet.context-path=/something
server.error.whitelabel.enabled = true

#overriding old spring beans with newer version
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true


#enable console logs
logging.level.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG



#Metrics related config
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.beans.enabled=false
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
management.server.port=8081
```

when i try to access this url - `http://localhost:8080/something/metrics` i am getting 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

By default, all actuator endpoints are mapped beneath `/actuator`. With a context path of `/something`, this means that the metrics endpoint would be available at `/something/actuator/metrics`.

Comment: So i added this properties here for some reason i am getting 404 not found when i access - http://localhost:8080/something/actuator/metrics but when i added management.server.port=8081 and tried to access http://localhost:8081/actuator/metrics then i am able to see the metrics.I have added management.properties above